# Cd to virtual environment instead of sourcing it

Tags: linux, python-3.x, virtualenv

I wonder if 'cd' directly to virtual environment is the same thing as sourcing the virtual environment. That is,

1. `source <venv_name>/bin/activate`
2. `cd <venv_name>/bin/`

Is (1) the same as (2)? I.e., is everything visible (1) also visible in (2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same thing.

1. `source <venv_name>/bin/activate`

This changes where the site-packages are resolved. It achieves this by one very simple hack: prepending the venv's bin dir on an environment variable ($PATH), which influences where the `python` command resolves.

2. `cd <venv_name>/bin/`

Changing dir into `<venv_name>/bin` will *not* make the packages installed in the `venv` (which are located in `../lib`) available for import. The command `python` will still resolve to `/usr/local/bin/python` (or wherever your system python interpreter is) and the interpreter will still be using the system site-packages. You won't see the venv's library.

Check the output of `python -m site` within and outside of your virtualenv to see the difference.

Comment: Hi, wim:

If so, is there any equivalent command I can issue to be inside the virtual environment without using source command?

Comment: You can use `. <venv_nam>/bin/activate`.  Or just execute the venv python directly:  `./<venv_name>/bin/python`.

Comment: What I want to see is the presence of files and modules that are only visible in virtual environment. Is there a way to make python see those files in the virtual environment without sourcing the <venv_name>/bin/activate file.

Comment: So, to make virtual-env-specific source files and modules visible to Python interpreter during execution, I should include <venv_name> in the import statements to make those modules/source codes visible then?

Comment: No, that won't work.  Activating the venv makes them available for import because it puts the venv site-packages dir available in `sys.path`.  Please try executing `python -m site` in and out of the virtualenv and check the differences, to understand what I'm getting at here.

Comment: I understand "source ./<venv-name>/bin/activate" would make venv-site packages available to compiler.

My question is there is not another equivalent command (I don't want to use 'source' or '.') to replace  "source ./<venv-name>/bin/activate" command at the prompt, isn't it?

Comment: I already answered this in comments above.  You may just execute the venv python directly: `/path/to/<venv_name>/bin/python`.  Then venv packages will be available for import.

Answer (score 1):

> Is (1) the same as (2)? I.e., is everything visible (1) also visible in (2)?

No. Those two commands do completely different things.

A virtual environment isn't a "thing" that you can "go in". When you source the virtual environment activation script, almost the only thing it does is set some environment variables.

If you don't want to run the activation script, you can manually set these variables.  You can't do it with a `cd` command, however.

Comment: What are the env. variables to be set that would equate to "source "<venv_name>"/bin/activate"?

Comment: @user1972031: When you source the script, it sets the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. Just look in the script and you can see exactly what it does.